# Deploy Storm topology via REST API

Tags: java, rest, apache-storm

Is there a way to deploy Storm topology via some kind of REST endpoint?
I've seen Storm REST endpoints, and I know I can activate or deactivate existing topologies, but what if I want to add new one?
Maybe there is some kind of way out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, topology submission is not available via REST API. We added it at Storm 0.10 beta but found security issue and decided to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you share what was the security concern?

Comment: @kgdinesh: Previous approach was uploading jar and specifying main class so that UI process can fetch and run main class via executing java command, which means anyone can make arbitrary code to be run in machine which UI is running on **via account which runs UI process**.